# Does CiviRules work with smart groups?

Tags: smartgroups, civirules

I've tried to create a rule where an email gets sent when a contact is "added" to a smart group.  By "added" I mean the condition that smart group is based upon is met.

As far as I can tell it doesn't.  It seems like it would be hard to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contacts don't really get 'added' to a smart group - it's more that when the smart group is used, a search is run to find who currently meets those criteria (glossing over some complex rebuild and caching details...)  So there is no specific event for CiviRules to react to in a post trigger.

You might be able to base something on the 'Daily trigger for group members' cron trigger and maybe modify it for a more frequent run.  See https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/trigger/

Comment: Likewise a parent group doesn't work either

Comment: @Paul-Tahoe I would not want CiviRules to work with smart groups, it would get far too complicated for me :-) I think you could solve it by changing the smart group to a normal group and use CiviRules to manage the group membership?

Comment: @ErikH-CiviCooP is it still the case that CiviRule doesn't support smart group triggers? I'm seeing Smart Groups in the list of Groups for a trigger in 2.13.

Comment: AFAIK but test :-) It might be that it does work. Personally I do not use Smart Groups in combination with CiviRules....

Comment: I used a smart group as the source for a daily trigger of group members and it worked.

Comment: Why can't I add a contact to a group that is Parent group?